# Understanding the printed value in C

Tags: c, pointers, vector

I have this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Funz(char *S);
int main()
{
        char S[100] = "abcdefghilmnopq";
        Funz(S);
    return 0;
}
void Funz(char *S)
{
    if ('\0' != S[0])
    { 
    Funz(S+1);
    printf("%c", *S);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the printed value is in the reverse order and not only "q".

Comment: recursive call: print in reverse.

Comment: thanks,thats clear, but does the last element get eliminated from the array when i have a recursive call? i dont get how after that `p` `o` ecc get printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Funz(S+1);
printf("%c", *S);
```

Here it is recursive call and `printf` is executed after that. So as to print each sub call has to be finished and then `printf` is executed. That's why it is printed in reverse.

Instead if you use loop and iterate, then you will get only `'q'`.

For example lets take a short string say `"abc"`-

```
                           Funz(s[0]) (0
                         /          \
                    Funz(s[1])(1   'a' (6
                   /           \
               Funz(s[2])(2  'b'(5
              /            \
            condition    'c'(4
            false (3
```

Order of execution  - `0 1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: thanks, but does the last element get eliminated from the array when i have a recursive call?

Comment: @totoro No, none of the elements as remove.

Answer (score 2):

because you're recursively calling `Funz(S)` before you print it. What happens is that the recursiveness eventually ends at `q` since that's the last letter before the null terminator.

After the null terminator exception has been caught and handled, then it returns to the previous function frame and prints the character.

If you wish to print it in order, you need to print the character THEN recurse it.

instead of having it coded like this:

```
void Funz(char *S)
{
    if ('\0' != S[0])
    { 
    Funz(S+1);
    printf("%c", *S);
    }
}
```

You should have it coded as:

```
void Funz(char *S)
{
    if ('\0' != S[0])
    { 
        printf("%c", *S);
        Funz(S+1);
    }
}
```